# Error 10061: No connection could be made - target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, https, cygwin

Ok, I am attempting to figure out how to get Python3 to support https. 
Am attempting to install a package via cygwin:

$ "$@"  pip install https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/download/attachments/23694554/ecmwf-api-client-python.tgz
I get the error boils down to this:

print "Python socket module was not compiled with SSL support. Aborting..."
                                                                                  ^
So, I wanted to check if Python was https compliant and used this code:

```
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 80

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
  s.connect((host, port))
  s.shutdown(2)
  print("Success connecting to ")
  print(host," on port: ",str(port))
except socket.error as e:
  print("Cannot connect to ")
  print(host," on port: ",str(port))
  print(e)
```

But I end up with the error:

```
Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1  on port:  80
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

All I want to do (as simplistic as possible please as I'm not a programmer, just someone who is using python temporarily to access some data) is make it so python doesn't give me this error so I can get the package to install.

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Python 3.3.2  Windows XP

Comment: Well, do you *have* a web-server running on your machine, listening on the standard port 80?

Comment: What do you have listening on port 80? Is it a webserver or do you have your own software (are you sure it listens on port 80 correctly?) and/or does your firewall allow it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no 'listener' on port 80. (And for checking HTTPS connections, it should be port 443, right?)

You need to start a web-server listening on the port 80.
For Windows, use XAMPP or WAMP server, which needs just one click of button to start the server on port 80. For Linux, I suggest Apache.