# Facing 'NewConnectionError' while installing steup wheel in windows

Tags: python, pip, locust

I have installed Python on Windows. When I tried to install other packages (pip, setuptools, wheel) I got a 'NewConnectionError' (see attached
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTi23.png)).

These are my settings:

- OS: Windows Server 16 Standard
- Python version: 3.6.6
- Locust version:
- pip version: 10.0.1

Comment: Hi Sampath, if you have issues with english, please use google translate. I can't really figure out what you are trying to do. You can paste your code here, it's easier than posting images.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you can't connect to the repository where the packages are.
I would suggest looking through similar questions here on StackOverflow. Try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12993276/222529) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19357848/222529), for starters.

Comment: May I also suggest that, in the future, you copy the relevant errors and paste them in your question, instead of attaching images. This makes it easier for people to research an answer and for others who face similar problems to find your post at a later stage.